# retrieving Owner name of file using getpwuid() in c always throw root

Tags: c, linux, getpwuid

Hi when i login as root in my Linux system and try to get owner name of the file Using getpwuid() it always display root(lie) rather than actual owner name below is my code. 
please help me to get the actually name rather then root.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        register struct passwd *access;
        register uid_t uid;
        int c;

        uid = geteuid ();
        access= getpwuid (uid);
        if (access)
        {
                puts (access->pw_name);
                exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        fprintf (stderr,"%s: cannot find username for UID %u\n",
                        _PROGRAM_NAME, (unsigned) uid);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

**I always get username as root how can i get the actually name of owner?**

Comment: Don't use `register`. It's pointless.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't use `stat`. You've either copied the wrong code or you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Please check udated my queation

Comment: What file are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geteuid()` gets the effective user ID that the process is currently running as. Since you're logged in as root, this will return UID 0 -- and `getpwuid()` will correctly tell you that this is root.

If you want to get the owner of a file, why are you using `geteuid()`? You need to call a function from the `stat()` family to get that information.